# Can i fetch data for a static react site (SSG) after build time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a small react site (3 pages) that's pre rendered and served as html from nginx. The site has one component that needs to pull data a very small amount of data from an api at run time (initial hydration when the site loads). The piece of data pulled is different for every user. Is that achievable in a react SSG app?

**if not what's the best approch, SSR seems a bit of an overkill for 3 pages?**

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("myApi")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setData({data}))
  },[])
```

Obviously a fetch like this won't work because it's being run once a t build time, but maybe including a runtime script?

Comment: Is this a next.js project?

Comment: Regardless something you can try is setting up a ‘cron’ task that runs every **x-interval** and runs the build command. You might even want to have it done in a separate directory and only replace the build directory once the new build is fully complete

Comment: No but I've looked over next and I didn't see a solution that dosen't involve SSR

Comment: 99 percent of the site is static the only different data is some details about the user visiting (a string of a few bytes)

Comment: You need to look into pre-rendering software or services like https://prerender.io that will fully render the page before sending it out if it detects a web scraper or bot. They integrate with nginx. If you want to host it somewhere besides your own server https://netlify.com also offers pre-rendering and free static site hosting

Answer (score 0):

The difference between SSG and SSR is when you calculate the html that is returned from the server.
With SSG it's rendered at build time, while with SSR at request time.
Obviously SSR has more computational overhead than SSG because of caching.

Therefore, when you want to retrieve user-specific data from the server, you don't need SSR to render the html from the server. Typically SSR is useful for dynamically generated data you care about for reasons of SEO (so in this case it doesn't apply since your data is user-specific), or faster perceived content rendering compared to CSR.

In your case you can just perform an ajax request at the client, passing a token to the server to identify the user and render the content client-side.

Comment: 99 percent of the data is static but the 1 percent that's dynamic it's the reason for the users to visit and it's spesific to them. SEO is very important and that;s why I need html to be present.

Comment: @docHoliday Yes, I mean just serve static html and retrieve the user-specific piece with ajax.

Comment: @html_programmer He wants open-graph tags to be present in the initial html document so that social media sites find it. However, what he wants to do is not possible without having a server to intercept certain requests and perform SSR at least once.

Comment: Where do I include the ajax? As far as i know an SSG like react-snap generates the fetch call once at build time. That means a user visting the website won't get the data.

Comment: @docHoliday The data is fetched by the browser when the page gets loaded. It is still a static html page without dynamic content.

Comment: @Abir Taheer I want to have a 99 perscent static website that's being served from nginx as html and pull 1 small JSON object from an api after the html has been served to the user.

Comment: @html_programmer How do you fetch data from a static html page after it's been served? At the moment the useEffect that pulls the data dosen't work after it's been turned to html.

Comment: @docHoliday If it's a client side script, `useEffect` is executed after the component was rendered. The point of React is to maintain a virtual DOM tree in memory, and will commit the required state updates to the actual DOM. So it should work. Btw, it is not executed at build time. The code is executed by the JS engine in your browser at runtime.